# Quartz.net - How to skip to next_fire_time?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.net to run the job. I am not able to find a way to skip the current trigger and wait for next fire time..

I want to run my job everyday at 3 AM to 6 AM. But I want to stop running and wait for next day if I get the status that I want before 6 AM.

Here is the code that I try but doesn't work. Any idea how to fix it?

**Program**

```
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail myjob = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("MyJob")
                    .Build();

        ITrigger myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("MyTrigger")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
                      x => x.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(3, 00))
                     .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(6, 00, 00))                         
                     .WithIntervalInSeconds(10))                
            .Build();


        scheduler.ScheduleJob(myjob , myTrigger );
```

**MyJob**

```
   public class MyJob: IInterruptableJob {

    static int i=0;

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) { 

        Console.WriteLine("Call WebService to get the status");

        i++; //Just to simulate the status
        if (i > 5) {  //Here, I got the status so stop the timer and run at next-fire-time

             ITrigger myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("MyTrigger")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
                      x => x.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(3, 00))
                     .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(6, 00, 00))                         
                     .WithIntervalInSeconds(10))                
            .Build();


            context.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(context.Trigger.Key, myTrigger );
        }

    public void Interrupt() {
        Console.WriteLine("Interrupt from MyJOb!");
    }
}
```

Comment: you could call the webservice to get the status inside the job code instead

Comment: Sorry about confusion.. ya. If you notice in MyJob, there is a code "if (i > 5) " and "Console.WriteLine("Call WebService to get the status");".. So I am already calling the service inside the job.. The question is how to stop it because it will run until the stop time. I want to stop the job when I got the correct status and I want the scheduler to wait for next schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I can't use this code below in MyJob class.

```
   context.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(context.Trigger.Key, myTrigger );
```

So, I have to change it like this..

```
   var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
   scheduler.RescheduleJob(context.Trigger.Key, aastarPreLoadTrigger);
```

But unfortunately, there is no support for async/await..

**Note:**

My new code fixed the rescheduling issue but didn't stop so I think I need to simple scheduler instead of daily timer and set the start date to next day.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
            x => x.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(iTimeFrom, iMinuteFrom))
                     .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(iTimeTo, iMinuteTo))                       
                     .WithIntervalInMinutes(iMinute)
                     .OnEveryDay()
                     )
        .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this code best answers the question will help to improve the long-term value of the answer and will help to prevent it from being deleted during review.